# Exponential decay with replenishment in sigma notation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, exponential-function

I was trying to figure out how to graph a number that grows by 200 each week and the total decays by 5% and eventually found the recurrence 
$$g(0)=0, g(n)=200 + 0.95 g(-1 + n)$$ 
which reduces to 
$$-4000 * (-1 + (19/20)^n)$$
Sure, that works.

In trying to find this answer I accidentally found an answer in sigma notation that has me scratching my head.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n 200*2.78951^{-0.05*(n-1)}$$
How does this almost perfectly reflect the recurrence and where does this 2.78951 come from?!?!
I came to the number by noticing using e was very close and adjusted the number until it was almost perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(19/20)^{-1/0.05}=2.78951$ is a special case of the large-$n$ approximation $(1-1/n)^{-n}\approx e$.